# "No Ethernet card" while installing debian stable

Tags: debian, system-installation

I have a new Intel NUC D54250WYK.  I would like to install the latest Debian stable version.  After successfully booting from a CD burned from debian-7.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso, the install fails with:

```
No Ethernet card was detected.  If you know the name of the
driver needed by your Ethernet card, you can select it from the list.
```

According to the specs, this machine has an Intel I218V Gigabit Ethernet controller.

I tried choosing the `e1000e` driver, but the same screen reappears.

When I go to the command line I can use lspci to see:

```
# lspci -v | grep Ethernet
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 1559 (rev 04)
```

Is this a matter of the installer not having the necessary updates for this hardware, or is this a problem with the hardware itself?

EDIT: I have subsequently also tried the debian-7.3.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso.  The same problem occurs.  This is the more detailed `lspci` output:

```
# lspci -vnnk -s 00:19.0
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1559] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2054]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
        Memory at f7c00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        Memory at f7c3c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
```

David

Comment: Please use `lspci -vnnk -s 00:19.0`.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to include the requested output.

Comment: Debian network installation CDs are quite less in size, and often doesn't have all the drivers -- I guess the ones that strictly do not comply with Debian policy. I usually download those specific drivers before hand, and put them in a USB drive, and use it during the installation. Otherwise, those packages could be installed later after the OS installation is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [thread on the Debian User Forums](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=106169&sid=1b4381ea1cd1581910e7b8003458bdb1) detailing a similar problem with a new Intel ethernet controller (though the controller itself is different than mine).  The suggestions there are to try the testing installers or to use a kernel from backports.

EDIT: I tried one of the weekly builds of Debian testing and Ethernet is now working in the installer.

Comment: Do you know where I can download a precompiled driver? I need a driver for Debian wheezy, i386, Ethernet Pro 100 rev 8 82557/8/9/0/1

Answer (score 1):

Not *being able to detect* an Ethernet card is usually a driver problem. The installer sees a component on your computer, but is unable to realise *"oh! that's an ethernet network card!*".

I would suggest you to use a more complete installer (from what you say, you are using a netinstaller, which is very very *very* minimal). Try using a complete ISO instead. See :

- http://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/
- http://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/#stable

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately I get the same result using debian-7.3.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look here (http://www.debian.org/CD/live/), and troubleshoot the bug from a Live Debian ? :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my advise - 
1. Finish your Debian installation, 
2 download the e1000e driver, 
3 download gcc deb package with all its dependencies
4. Extract driver and install -  http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products/000005480.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem while attempting to install the linux Parrot OS on my HP Pavillion x360 over and over, but I continued with the installation anyway. After the installation finished and I rebooted my laptop, sure enough there was no ehternet card or networks for that matter available.

Then I remembered that I had one of those Mickey Mouse network adpter cards around my apartment, so I went ahead and inserted it on the usb port and guess what? It worked!

Maybe is not the best technical thing to do but it resolved my issue and I now able to navigate the web as usual.

Comment: Sorry, I should have say " navigate the web as usual"

Comment: Nothing Mickey Mouse about this at all.  I have a cheap lousy USB 1.1 network card kicking around precisely because it will work with pretty much any Linux/BSD installer, and I have on occasion needed it.  You just need something good enough to get you to the point where you can load the driver for the card you really want to use.